# reCAPTCHA v2 (No CAPTCHA) fails in Twitter Bootstrap popovers

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, recaptcha

I've been trying to implement the new recaptcha inside of Bootstrap popovers (popups). It works in fallback mode, however in standard mode it only works when only the “I'm not a robot” checkbox is needed, and not with the additional popup puzzle, which does pop but gets destroyed instantly.

I don't know if the error comes from Bootstrap / jQuery code, from Google's or my own. Has anyone got any suggestions?

Here is my code so far, which requires an API key:

```js
//prevent links
$(document).on("click", "a", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
});

$(document).on("click", "button", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
});
// new beverage popup handler
$('#button').popover({
  selector: '#new_popup',
  placement: 'auto',
  container: 'body',
  html: true,
  // trigger:'focus',
  title: function() {
    return $("#popover-head").html();
  },
  content: function() {
    //create div for actual popover, to get info in handler below
    var content = $('#popover-content').clone();
    var captcha_div = content.find("#captcha")[0];
    console.log(captcha_div);
    grecaptcha.render(captcha_div, {
      'sitekey': 'some-key'
    });
    return '<div id="actual-popover-content">' + content.html() + '</div>';
  }
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="jumbotron">

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <div class="panel panel-default" , id="button">
            <button class="form-control pop-function" id="new_popup" rel="popover">Add entry</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <!-- popover -->
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <div id="popover-head" class="hide">New entry</div>
          <div id="popover-content" class="input-group hide">
            <div class="list-group">
              <form>
                <div class="input-group">
                  <input type="text" class="list-group-item form-control" placeholder="Name">
                  <span class="input-group-addon">Name</span>
                </div>

                <div class="input-group" id="captcha"></div>
                <br>
                <button class="btn btn-primary">Add</button>
              </form>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src='http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?hl=en&render=explicit' async defer></script>
```

Comment: did you found the solution yet?